# Jquery doesn't load correctly in dinamically created elements inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Im using datatables.net and boostrap with hover effects on image. 
The image inside expanded table must work the same as the images outside the table, can't find the reason it doesn't:

http://jsfiddle.net/rokas_m/rqokaub2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>timeline</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeline2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<style>

.thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.75);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
 img {
            max-height: none;
            min-height: 0;
                   }
                    td.details-control {
        background: url('https://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        tr.shown td.details-control {
            background: url('https://www.datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-8">


                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                        <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th >Pavadinimas</th>
                <th >Antraštė</th>
                <th>Tipas</th>
                <th>Išsiuntimo / gavimo data</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Dokumento nr.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    </table>
         <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h6>Dokumentas.doc</h6>

                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="View">Žiūrėti</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Add">Pridėti</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/64/pdf-icon.png" alt="..."></img>
                </div>
                                       </div>   
                                <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h6>Dokumentas.doc</h6>

                    <p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="View">Žiūrėti</a>
                    <a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Add">Pridėti</a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/64/word-doc-icon.png" alt="..."></img>
                </div>
                                       </div>                         


                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

<script>
     /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table>'+
        '<tr >'+
            '<td><strong>Dokumentai:&#160;</strong></td>'+
           '<td><div>'+
             '<div class="thumbnail">'+
                '<div class="caption">'+
                    '<h6>'+d.dokumentai+'</h6>'+                    
                   '<p><a href="" class="label label-danger" rel="tooltip" title="View">Žiūrėti</a>'+
                    '<a href="" class="label label-default" rel="tooltip" title="Add">Pridėti</a></p>'+
                '</div>'+
                    '<img src="'+d.dok_ikona+'"></img>'+
                    '</div>'+
             '</div></td>'+ 



        '</tr>'+

    '</table>';

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "paging":   false,
        "searching": false,
        "data": [
    {
      "pavadinimas": "Pretenzijos, reikalavimai Biurui",
      "antraste": "Dėl išmokos",
      "tipas": "Gautas",
      "siunt_gav_data": "2015/08/24",
      "data": "2011/04/25",
      "dok_nr": "G00-100",
      "dokumentai": "dokumentas.doc",
      "dok_ikona": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/64/pdf-icon.png"
    },
    {
      "pavadinimas": "Pretenzijos, reikalavimai Biurui",
      "antraste": "Dėl išmokos",
      "tipas": "Gautas",
      "siunt_gav_data": "2015/08/25",
      "data": "2011/04/26",
      "dok_nr": "G00-101", 
      "dokumentai": "dokumentas.pdf",
       "dok_ikona": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/64/pdf-icon.png"


    }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "pavadinimas" },
            { "data": "antraste" },
            { "data": "tipas" },
            { "data": "siunt_gav_data" },
            { "data": "data" },
            { "data": "dok_nr" }
        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0,1,2,3 ] }
       ]
          } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }

    } );
} );

             $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    

    $('.thumbnail').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    ); 
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rqokaub2/1/

I Changed that part:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
  }
);
```

and use that:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.thumbnail', function(){
  $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.thumbnail', function(){
  $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
});
```

Binding functions using `hover`/`click` etc. directly will be applied only for loaded elements. But when you use `on` method (in the past `live`) all elements (event those which are already not loaded will be binded). `on` method is very useful especially when you use a lot of content loaded via AJAX

Comment: Wonderful!  Works pefectly

Answer (score 0):

When you reach this line of code:

```
 $('.thumbnail').hover(
```

the table has not been filled yet; so that in the function that is handling the "plus" sign click you have to add again the code that is make the hover effect in the outer images.

Comment: ye this is the problem, but can't see the solution.

Comment: you have to add the hover effect just right after the image in the table is shown (righet after the "// Open this row" code)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for image hover:

```
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    
 $(document).on("mouseenter", ".thumbnail", function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250); //.fadeIn(250)
});
 $(document).on("mouseleave", ".thumbnail", function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250); //.fadeOut(205)
});
```

fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rokas_m/rqokaub2/)